# What visa type should I need for short-term visiting about a research project in Italy?

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas, italy

I'm a non-British researcher currently living in UK, I want to visit Italy for a research project with an Italy university for about 15 days.
What type of visa should I need? I searched in schengenvisainfo.com but I'm confused between study, business and tourism visa. Also, do I need any specified document for that type of visa?

Comment: Will you be in a mobility/exchange agreement? Will you get paid? Are you officially enrolled by an Italian University?


You don't give us enough info here, anyways, contact your local Italian consulate before doing anything

Comment: So I need some kind of letter or invitation in the application? I'm just a researcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the information we have, you probably qualify for the Research visa.

You'll find all the info and how to apply, in the official Italian visa [site](https://vistoperitalia.esteri.it/home/en#BMQuestionario)

Assuming a random citizenship, you need (this might change from nationalities to nationalities) :

- Entry visa application form
- recent passport-size photograph
- valid travel document whose expiry date is three months longer than that of the visa requested
- proof that the applicant has accommodation in Italy: hotel booking, declaration of hospitality
- proof that the applicant has sufficient means of subsistence for their stay in Italy, for an amount not lower than that specified in Table A annexed to the Directive of the Ministry of the Interior dated 1st March 2000 ( View )
- health insurance, if the foreign national is not entitled to health care in Italy by virtue of agreements or conventions in force with their country
- enrolment or pre-enrolment in the course to be followed in Italy

> So I need some kind of letter or invitation in the application?

Yes, you would have needed that for any type of visas (if you don't show that you will have your visa denied).
Either a proof of enrollment or signed letter from someone there that certifies you have enrolled in the course

You'll find the localized info here on [VFS UK site](https://visa.vfsglobal.com/one-pager/italy/uk/london/#Research)

Comment: Thanks, one more thing I want to be clear is that, yesterday I tried to book an appointment in vfs, when selecting the type of visa it showed that I can choose 1 in 4 types which are business, D category, study and tourism. Which one should I choose?

Comment: Contact the italian consulate, this might be taken as a special visa category @Teewip

Comment: EDIT : @Teewip, I've edited the relevant page for Research visa on VFS UK site